# Is there a way to reply to a sender with his own message?

Tags: vba, outlook

In outlook, I want all the people sending me emails with the object as "testintro" let's say, to be replied with their OWN email. I want them to receive exactly what they sent me. Is it possible to create that rule?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But not with a rule. Instead, you can develop a VBA macro.

You can create a VBA macro where you could handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.

So, you may get an instance of the arrived mail item and call the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)) method to reply instantly. The method creates a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message. You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How To: Change an Outlook e-mail message before sending using C# or VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/12/outlook-change-message-before-sending/)